# Regex for URL to hyperlink

Tags: regex, actionscript, flex4

At the moment, I have the following regex for replacing a URL to a HTML hyperlink:

```
msg = msg.replace(/(\b((https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gi, "<a href='out.php?u=$1'>$1</a>");
```

This replaces

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

into

```
<a href='out.php?u=http://www.stackoverflow.com'>http://www.stackoverflow.com</a>
```

---

But now I have a problem. When I already have a hyperlink, I don't want to replace the URL inside that hyperlink to a new hyperlink.

So:

```
<a href='http://www.stackoverflow.com'>Stackoverflow</a>
```

must not become:

```
<a href='<a href='out.php?u=http://www.stackoverflow.com'>http://www.stackoverflow.com</a>'>Stackoverflow</a>
```

---

Does somebody know how I can prevent this?

Comment: I think this has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've already fixed it by adding a white space before and after the string, and replaces all URLs with a whitespace before and after:

```
msg = " " + msg + " ";
msg = msg.replace(/(\s)(((https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])(\s)/gi, " <a target='_blank' href=\"" + websiteUrl + "/out.php?u=$2\"><font color='" + hyperlinkColor + "'>$2</font></a> ");
msg = StringUtil.trim(msg);
```

This doesn't replace all the hyperlinks, because a hyperlink doesn't have whitespaces before and after the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a negative look-ahead assert, written as (?!expression).  So...

```
?!(\<a)/(\b((https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gi, "<a href='out.php?u=$1'>$1</a>");
```